# Dynamically Change Div Content in Rails 4.1.4

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I've spent almost my entire day trying to figure out how to solve this dilemma but unfortunately a majority of the solutions I've found are related to an outdated Rails version that still allowed "render" to be used in assets.

**Here's what I'm trying to do:**
My view finds each "Trip" entry and displays each as a thumbnail on the page.  When the user clicks on each thumbnail, I would like the additional details (and also associations, each trip has a has_many: weeks) to be rendered in the Div below those thumbnails (replacing the previous content).

I can't seem to get Ajax to work and after several hours of attempting finally learned that "render" can't be used in assets.  I would sincerely appreciate any help and along with potential solutions if someone could provide a possible reference guide for Ajax with Rails 4 that would be fantastic because I can't seem to find one.

Here's my code:

View - index.html.erb

```
<div>
<ul class="thumbnails col-md-offset-2">
    <% Trip.find_each do |trip| %>
    <li class="col-md-3" style="list-style-type:none;">
        <%= link_to image_tag("http://placehold.it/350x350", :border => 0), :class => 'thumbnail', :url=>'/trips/selected_trip/params', :remote => true %>
        <h3><%= trip.name %></h3>
    </li>
    <% end %>
</ul>
    <div id="selected_trip">
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller - trips.controller.rb

```
class TripsController < ApplicationController
before_filter :authenticate_user!
after_action :verify_authorized

def index
    @trips = Trip.all
    authorize Trip
end

def new
    @trip = Trip.new
    authorize Trip
end

def create
    @trip = Trip.new(trip_params)
    authorize Trip

    if @trip.save
        flash[:notice] = "New trip has been created."
        redirect_to @trip
    else
        #Fill me in
    end
end

def edit
    @trip = Trip.find(params[:id])
    authorize Trip
end

def update
    @trip = Trip.find(params[:id])
    authorize Trip
    @trip.update(trip_params)
    flash[:notice] = "Trip has been updated."
    redirect_to @trip
end

def show
    @trip = Trip.find(params[:id])
    authorize Trip
end

def destroy
    @trip = Trip.find(params[:id])
    authorize Trip
    @trip.destroy

    flash[:notice] = "Trip has been deleted."

    redirect_to trips_path
end

def selected_trip
  @trip = Trip.find(params[:id])
  @trip.name

  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
end

private
    def trip_params
        params.require(:trip).permit(:name, :description, :status)
    end
end
```

Javascript - trips.js.erb (I know this method doesn't work anymore with render not being available in assets)

```
$('#selected_trip').html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'selected_trip', :content_type => 'text/html'%>")
```

Partial - _selected_trip.html.erb

```
<p>Success!</p> <!-- Just for testing, will replace with actual content -->
```

Thanks,
Nate

Edit 11:10PM (it works)-
I've changed my controller to:

```
def selected_trip
  @trip = Trip.find(params[:id])
  authorize Trip
  render :partial => 'selected_trip', :content_type => 'text/html'
end
```

and my view to:

```
<div>
<ul class="thumbnails col-md-offset-2">
    <% Trip.find_each do |trip| %>
    <li class="col-md-3" style="list-style-type:none;" data-tripID="<%= trip.id %>">
        <%= link_to image_tag("http://placehold.it/350x350", :border => 0), selected_trip_trip_path(trip), :class => 'thumbnail', :remote => true %>
        <h3><%= trip.name %></h3>
    </li>
    <% end %>
</ul>
    <div id="selected_trip">
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<script>
$('a.thumbnail').on('ajax:success', function(evt, data) {
  var target = $('#selected_trip');
  $(target).html(data);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Where did you see you can't render partials from JS in Rails 4? I think that is a false statement.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8370399/rails-js-erb-file-cannot-find-method-render

Right here

Comment: that answer is from 2011. Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18843185/rails-4-ajax-update-div

Comment: I did see that but thought I found another comment mentioning it was the same in Rails 4.  Regardless I gave that another shot but got a similar error as before, "undefined method `render' for #<#<Class:0x007fbd05446258>:0x007fbd079814a0>"

Used $('#selected_trip').html("<%= escape_javascript(render @trip) %>") passing @trip = current_trip through the controller

Comment: Check my answer. Let's see if that helps. If you have several containers to show the results, you don't want to have them with the same id #selected_trip. Somehow you want to create attributes that will let you uniquely identify which thumbnail created the AJAX request, and where the responses need to be rendered (take a look at data attributes for that).

Comment: I'm giving it a shot right now, thanks... I only want to render the results in the same container (overwriting previous results).  Ideally I want to send the trip.id along with the AJAX request so that it can return the proper results (since each thumbnail src is going to be an image location from the database associated with the trip in the "do" loop), should I be adding a data attr that = the trip.id or is that overkill in this situation?

Comment: It is completely fine to add a data attribute to store the id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to avoid rendering from the assets, you can try doing it this way.

I am assuming you know where you need to put the listener in order to catch the AJAX call, and also you can figure out, where you want to place the results when the AJAX comes back with a success status. Then, you want to do something like this:

```
$('whatever_container_they_can_click').on('ajax:success', function(evt, data) {
  var target = $('#selected_trip'); // Find where is the destination
  $(target).html(data);
});
```

Change your controller action to:

```
def selected_trip
  @trip = Trip.find(params[:id])
  render :partial => 'selected_trip', :content_type => 'text/html'
end
```

Comment: I think part of my confusion is where and how to make the AJAX call in the first place (do I just use the current :url method within my link_to tag or create an entirely new on_click method using pure jquery?).  I think what you've posted makes sense -- the render :partial gets returned as data from the AJAX call and inserted into the HTML (am I correct on this?).

Also just a quick note that .live was deprecated in 1.7 so I think .on has to be used now.

Comment: If you add the option ``:remote => true`` to your link_to, it will do an AJAX request.

Comment: I'm glad! Maybe you should take a look at this guide: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html